# how can i import acm.program in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I watched one of the [Stanford online video lectures](http://see.stanford.edu/see/courseinfo.aspx?coll=824a47e1-135f-4508-a5aa-866adcae1111) about java programming. The course relies on the acm.program, but when I try to import it using Eclipse, an error message ("The import acm cannot be resolved") appears. How should I deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to download the `jar` file from the [ACM Java Task Force website](http://jtf.acm.org/).  You will then need to make sure that the `acm.jar` file is in your classpath.